# python append dictionary instance

Tags: python, dictionary

The below block of code is inside a for loop and above this code block is information which populates the building, switch_ip, max and total variables in the dictionary.

```
data1 = { building { switch_ip:
               { 'max': MAX,
                 'total': total
               }
             }
           }
```

when I run the code, the output is:

```
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.10': {'max': '10', 'total': '43'}}}
```

There is much more data, and this output suggests to me that with each iteration of the for loop, the dictionary is being populated with new values. If I run a print statement within the for loop this is the output:

```
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.10': {'max': '10', 'total': '43'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.12': {'max': '0', 'total': '43'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.14': {'max': '1', 'total': '57'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.15': {'max': '2', 'total': '33'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.19': {'max': '0', 'total': '57'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.20': {'max': '0', 'total': '57'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.23': {'max': '1', 'total': '57'}}}
{'Azalea': {'10.16.62.24': {'max': '0', 'total': '57'}}}
```

This output is the data that I would like to have in one dictionary. How could I go about appending each instance of this dictionary into one dictionary?

Comment: What `key` will you like to have for that one parent dictionary?

Comment: The parent dictionary key will change because it's associated with a dictionary that compares an IP prefix to different buildings. So, ideally I would like to keep that key a variable.

Comment: So, how about you create these `data1` dicts inside your for loop and append them into a list and then you can have some IP prefix as key and this `list of dicts` as value for the parent dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for building in buildings:
    data1[building].update({ switch_ip:
                               { 'max': MAX,
                                 'total': total
                               }}
```

This would result in a data structure something like:

```
{'Azalea': { '10.16.62.10': { 'max': '10', 'total': '40' }},
           { '10.16.62.12': { 'max': '12', 'total': '32' }}}
```